# Сам себя запутал ))) Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Фрагмент кода для теста:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


useragent = UserAgent()

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)

options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
executable_path="...................",
options=options
)

driver.get(url='https://old.bankrot.fedresurs.ru/MessageWindow.aspx?ID=3E87DF86D20F7FE8C6B426A455B4A75D')
data_all_lots = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lotInfo').find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'odd')
for lot_info_full in data_all_lots:
    lot_info = lot_info_full.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    for tag in lot_info:
        tag_text = tag.text
        print(tag_text)
        description = #Описание
        category = #Классификация имущества
        starting_price = #Начальная цена
        price_reduction_information = #Информация о снижении цены
```

Как вытащить description  category starting_price price_reduction_information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lots = []

for lot_info_full in data_all_lots:
    lot_info = lot_info_full.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    lot = {
        'category': lot_info[6].text,
        'description': lot_info[1].text,
        'starting_price': lot_info[2].text,
        'price_reduction_information': lot_info[3].text

    }
    lots.append(lot)
print(lots)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное)

Comment: Позвольте еще один вопрос. В некоторых лотах в категории он возвращает 2 тега. 
({'category': 'Здания (кроме жилых) и сооружения, не включенные в 
другие группировки\nПрочее')
Как избавится от \nПрочее?